# How to convert a python list containing several lists into single list?

Tags: python, list, sublist

How do I convert a list of lists to a single list?

Input:

```
a=[['AA'], ['AE'], ['AH'], ['AO'],]
```

Desired output:

```
['AA','AE','AH','AO']
```

Comment: `a = [x for y in a for x in y]`

Comment: correct it is a duplicate. I removed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
a=[['AA'], ['AE'], ['AH'], ['AO'],]

l=[]

for i in a:
      l.extend(i)

print l
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use comprehension list:

or using `map` and `lambda functions`

```
a=[['AA'], ['AE'], ['AH'], ['AO'],]
# open the item [0] with generators
Newa = [x[0] for x in a]
>>>['AA', 'AE', 'AH', 'AO']
```

see examples: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: What if there are more than one element in the nested lists?

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:

```
for i, value in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = value[0]
```

Comment: I edited it. Now it works.